# parse logfile with inconsistent data to XML structure using c#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, logfile

using [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972965.aspx) greate tutorial.

it a easy example with great filled logfile like this:

```
25/05/2002   21:49   Search   Dozer   Anita1
25/05/2002   21:51   Update   Dozer   Anita1
26/05/2002   11:02   Search   Manda   Gerry2k
26/05/2002   11:12   Update   Manda   Gerry2k
27/05/2002   15:34   Search   Anka   Anita1
12/08/2002   10:14   Search   Amber   Huarez
```

i have inconsistent logfile like:

```
25/05/2002   21:49   Search   Dozer   Anita1
25/05/2002   21:51   Update           Anita1
26/05/2002           Search   Manda   Gerry2k
26/05/2002   11:12   Update   Manda   
27/05/2002   15:34             Anka   Anita1
             10:14   Search   Amber   Huarez
```

what can i to to prevent exceptions if some fields are empty?
[image]

its a code

```
 xmlFile.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlFile.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlFile.WriteStartElement("lines");

        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (line.Contains("\t"))
            {
                string[] items = line.Split('\t');


                xmlFile.WriteStartElement("line");

                xmlFile.WriteElementString("id",items[0]);
                xmlFile.WriteElementString("mandant", items[1]);
                xmlFile.WriteElementString("datetime", items[2]);
                xmlFile.WriteElementString("t_m", items[3]);
                xmlFile.WriteElementString("user", items[4]);
                xmlFile.WriteElementString("action", items[5]);
                xmlFile.WriteElementString("info", items[6]);

                xmlFile.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }

        xmlFile.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlFile.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd presume that the issue only occurs when the last item is missing, 
since missing items in the middle would still have a tab delimeter at the end.

In this case, you should probably use an inline conditional to check that you have a value present:

```
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("id", (items.Length > 0 ? items[0] : ""));
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("mandant", (items.Length > 1 ? items[1] : ""));
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("datetime", (items.Length > 2 ? items[2] : ""));
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("t_m", (items.Length > 3 ? items[3] : ""));
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("user", (items.Length > 4 ? items[4] : ""));
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("action", (items.Length > 5 ? items[5] : ""));
            xmlFile.WriteElementString("info", (items.Length > 6 ? items[6] : ""));
```

Soing this will give you default empty strings in slots that are past the end of record.